# Jetty serve file within Tar file

Tags: servlets, jetty, tar

Given that Jetty/Tomcat is configured and able to serve tar files, is there a built in mechanism or avaialble plugin to have a file within the tar served up?

i.e.

http:/localhost:8080/app/file.tar would return the whole tar file as normal

but something like

http:/localhost:8080/app/file.tar/path/to/file/in/archive.txt would return the file from within the archive.

I can write a servlet to handle this if required, just want to make sure I am not missing something that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up creating a Servlet that utilises [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html) which implements a Virtual File System and does exacly what I need.

i.e:

```
http://localhost:8080/files/file1.tar!/1/somefile.jar!/index.txt
```

returns the file index.txt within /1/somefile.jar found in /files/file1.tar on the file system.

Comment: i was going to say you could adapt something like the ResourceHandler to do this, but a servlet is a fine option as well